# If $P'AP$ is a spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix $A$ then prove that $A$ is positive definite iff $P'AP$ also positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

If $P'AP$ is a spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix $A$ then prove that

> $A$ is positive definite iff $P'AP$ also positive definite.

### definition:

A matrix $A$ is said to be positive definite if 
for all non-zero $x$, $x'Ax>0$.

Comment: $\langle P'AP x, x\rangle=\langle AP x, Px\rangle$ and $\langle A x, x\rangle=\langle APP'x, PP'x\rangle=\langle P'AP(P'x), (P'x)\rangle$

Comment: $A$ and $P'AP$ are similar and therefore have the same eigenvalues, so either all are positive (in which case both are positive definite), or not!

Comment: I think I require that A has to be singular since I spectral decompostion is used then your proof is correct...@M.Vinay

Comment: @gloom Singular? Did you mean diagonalizable? [A singular matrix cannot be positive definite, only positive semi-definite at best]. Even without referring to spectral decomposition, similar matrices have the same spectrum, so this result is true for *any* pair of similar matrices (not only for $A$ and its diagonalization $P'AP$). However, we can also prove it without using eigenvalues, by observing that $x' P' A P x = (Px)' A (Px) > 0$, since $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: yes..Thank you..@M.Vinay